# How to automatically share YouTube like/comment to Google Plus?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I can automatically post my YouTube likes/comments to my Facebook & Twitter accounts but cannot find the same thing for Google Plus. It's funny! Below is the settings page for sharing of a YouTube account.

If you know how to do it, please share.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can share the videos you like on Google+.

This screenshot says everything:

[image: How to Share YouTube Videos online on Google+]

Comment: I think the OP is talking about the feature that automatically posts the like of a YouTube video to Facebook (or Twitter). If you connect your Facebook account to your YouTube account, when you click the Like button under the video, it is automatically posted on your Facebook wall—the Google+ action is not automatic, there is an intermediate manual step.

Comment: @Alex I know, and this is an alternative option available as there seems to be no way to do what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Alex You got my gut ^^

Comment: @myselfpoddar I want it `auto` not `an manual alternative` - thank you very much any way

Answer (score 0):

When you're logged in to your Google account (and you have G+ one) the "thumbs up" icon beneath the video is replaced with "G+ Share". Clicking that will cause the video clip to appear in your G+ stream.